# How to build Angular 4 app & Angular 5 app at the same machine?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have already @angular/cli@1.4.5 installed globally. Is there a way to install @angular/cli@latest locally to build Angular 5 app?

```
$ ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 6.11.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.6
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
@angular/language-service: 4.3.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Comment: I have the same problem - needing to build/maintain Ang4 and Ang5 projects on the same Mac, but I suspect it means more than AngularCLI version control, and there are several packages that needed to have been installed with "save dev" vs "global".  So, answer-givers please address the complete solution...like maybe a full blog post or article reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to use [npx](https://github.com/zkat/npx):

```
npx @angular/cli@latest new <project>
```

`npx` should already be included with `npm` and other node binaries if you're using a relatively new version.

You could also install this CLI locally and use that local installation to create a new project:

```
cd <helper>
npm init
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
cd ..
<helper>/node_modules/.bin/ng new <project>
```

It's a bit silly, but you can't use `ng new` on the directory you are already in. The above should work without any big issues, but the `npx` route should be a lot simpler.